# Python: Inserting counts in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, insert, count, tuples

I am trying to insert "counts" (starting from 0) in a list of tuples. I have something like this:

```
list = [(1, 'Cat', 200, 3.2), (4, 'Dog', 204, 4.1), (2, 'Rabbit', 519, 2.0)]
```

and I want it to be like this:

```
list = [(1, 'Cat', 200, 0, 3.2), (4, 'Dog', 204, 1, 4.1), (2, 'Rabbit', 519, 2, 2.0)]
```

I tried something like this:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> for line in list:
...     list.insert(-2,i)
...     i+=1
...     print list
```

but it inserts all the counts between tuples, which is not what I want. Could anybody help a Python-beginner struggling with this? Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a job for `namedtuple`.

Comment: Thank you! I will study about [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [11]: lis=[(1, 'Cat', 200, 3.2), (4, 'Dog', 204, 4.1), (2, 'Rabbit', 519, 2.0)]

In [12]: lis=map(list,lis) #convert tuples to list


In [13]: lis       #now lis is list of lists instead of list of tuples
Out[13]: 
[[1, 'Cat', 200, 3.2000000000000002],
 [4, 'Dog', 204, 4.0999999999999996],
 [2, 'Rabbit', 519, 2.0]]

#use enumerate() for indexes, no need of manual indexing

In [14]: for i,x in enumerate(lis):
    x.insert(-1,i)                #insert at -1 not -2
   ....:     
   ....:     

In [15]: lis
Out[15]: 
[[1, 'Cat', 200, 0, 3.2000000000000002],
 [4, 'Dog', 204, 1, 4.0999999999999996],
 [2, 'Rabbit', 519, 2, 2.0]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, it did convert tuples to lists and what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is a tuple, then the count `i` can be inserted at the requested place by slicing the tuple and concatenating it back together:

```
x[:3] + (i,) + x[3:]
```

where `(i,)` is the (somewhat awkward) syntax for creating a one-element tuple. E.g.

```
>>> x = (1, 'Cat', 200, 3.2)
>>> x[:3] + (0,) + x[3:]
(1, 'Cat', 200, 0, 3.2)
```

Note that this creates a new tuple. You cannot modify an existing tuple in Python; for that, you'd need a list.

The reason why your code is inserting the counts in between tuples is because you're confusing the `list` and `line` variables; you're operating on `list` instead its elements.

(But when you find yourself handling five-element tuples, you should start thinking of using either `namedtuple` or custom classes.)

Comment: All true, but worth noting that this is creating new tuples, not modifying in place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could I do this for list of tuples as well? The original data is big sets of tuples...

Comment: @owl: you could do this in a list comprehension: `[x[:3] + (i,) + x[3:] for i, x in enumerate(list)]`. (`enumerate` generates the `i` for you.) Note that that gives you a new list, it doesn't modify `list` in-place. You could also just set `list[i] = list[i][:3] + (i,) + list[i][3:]` inside the loop.

Comment: Great! This worked very nicely too!! :) Thank you so much!! I wish I could accept several answers!!! I learned a lot today!

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify tuples. Use lists inside. Also try not name variables after other classes (list is a class name).

```
data = [[1, 'Cat', 200, 3.2], [4, 'Dog', 204, 4.1], [2, 'Rabbit', 519, 2.0]]
for index, line in enumerate(data):
    line.insert(-1,index)
    print(data)
```

If you want to go from your original list of tuples, one easy way to is make a copy in the loop:

```
newdata=[]
for index, line in enumerate(data):
    linecopy = list(line)
    linecopy.insert(-1,index)
    newdata.append(linecopy)
    print(newdata)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How could I convert tuples inside to lists? I am looking up and tried newlist = str(list).replace('[]'. '()') but did not work...

Comment: @owl - if you have a tuple stored in the variable `the_tuple` then `list(the_tuple)` will create a list. Note however that it will only convert the top level, so `list((1,2,3)) == [1,2,3]` but `list((1,2,(3,4))) == [1,2,(3,4)]`

Comment: Oh, I see. That gives answer to some of the issues I had earlier when I was trying to convert between types!

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable (which means they can't be changed after creation). You will need to make a NEW tuple and store that instead. Try this:

```
def insert_counts(old_list):
    new_list = []
    i=0
    for old_tuple in old_list:
        new_tuple = (old_tuple[0:2] + (i,) + old_tuple[2:])
        new_list.append(new_tuple)
        i+=1
    return new_list
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer too! I am so sorry I am asking such a basic question but how could I actually get new_list? I could not print it out...

Comment: @owl - It returns the newly created list, so you will need to assign it to a variable, `mylist = insert_counts(original_list); print mylist` or print it directly, `print insert_counts(original_list)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering to such a basic question! Yes, this also worked! As I wrote below, I really wish I could accept several answers! All are really good answers! Thank you so much! :)